# Let X11 window open in specific size and position

Tags: x11, osx, zathura

I installed `zathura` via `homebrew` from [this](https://github.com/zegervdv/homebrew-zathura) github repository. It works well, but the window which `zathura` creates is an `X11` (`XQuartz`) window which can't be controlled with `BetterTouchTool`. So I only can manually resize and reposition the window. Instead of installing an additional window manager I'd then just let `zathura` spawn all it's windows in a certain size and position. I know about the `.Xdefaults` file in my home directory, but since `zathura` itself is not an `X11` application I can't just write e.g.

```
zathura*geometry: 1050x750
```

**My question is**: How can I manage to let a non-`X11` application (in this case `zathura`) which spawns an `X11` window, spawn all windows in a certain size and position by default?

Versions:

- OS: OS X 10.11.6
- Homebrew 1.3.2-62-gdce8938
- zathura 0.3.7

Comment: Wondering the same!

Comment: If an application create an X11 window, then it is an X11 application. Or dose it create another process, that creates the X11 window?

Comment: I believe the most reliable way is to just write a sample x-client that listens for all new windows, finds the ones spawned by zathura (either by title or resource/class) then issues a configure_request to resize the window to whatever you want.

Comment: Not a proper solution, but to adjust the window to 500x700+20+10 geometry (500 width, 700 height, 20 from the left, 10 from the top) right after it has been mapped, you could use Xdotool: `zathura --fork 1.pdf && xdotool sleep 0.2 getactivewindow windowsize 500 700 windowmove 20 10`.